# things that shouldn't be allowed to exist / empty places that shouldn't be allowed to exist

Tags: grammar

Context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxDUQ2jCgHk&feature=youtu.be&t=33m4s

**"With enough time, I think things come into existence in empty places that shouldn't be allowed to exist."**

Does **"that shouldn't be allowed to exist"** modify **"empty places"**? Or does it modify **"things"**?

If you don't understand my question, I can describe it another way. Does the original sentence, **"With enough time, I think things come into existence in empty places that shouldn't be allowed to exist."** mean **"With enough time, I think things that shouldn't be allowed to exist come into existence in empty places."**?

Answer (score 1):

When reading your example, according to the **Law Of Proximity**

> that shouldn't be allowed to exist

may be thought to refer to

> empty places

However, the next passage in the clip talks about the "***empty places***" being home to things that are *dangerous*, so it is obvious that your phrase refers to

> things *(that)* come into existence